# How to not Verify SharePoint Links Access​?

Tags: vba, email, sharepoint, outlook, hyperlink

This [new functionality](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-link-preview-in-outlook-com-and-outlook-on-the-web-ebbfd8ce-d38e-40ef-bb8c-a5362e881163) - Link Preview / Verify Links Access / Verify Recipients Access - for MS Outlook desktop app, was ported from Web based app without changes to UI settings to [turn off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/450817/need-to-disable-pop-up-34some-recipients-don39t-ha.html).

[image]

[image]

I have no idea how to skip it.

The execution of code is stuck on `NewEmail.Send` until the window receives "Send" or "Send Anyway" msg.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, I was banging my head for 2 weeks trying to find a window by its name, etc...
and when I was in the middle of writing this plea for help one last idea came to my mind.
To comment out following line:

`NewEmail.Display`

It worked. From all of the sub-ideal solutions, this one is kind of satisfying. You can always put `.Display` in ErrorHandler. This line is here in first place, because many of macros are being run with task scheduler on VDIs/NPSAs, but some of them are being run by users, so `.Display` and `.Send` are always there as a comment or as a code.

I wonder if you have any other ways to manage this change until they will provide registry key or update the UI?